# How can I save an object to a file in Dart and read it again?

Tags: flutter, dart, object-serialization

I have already done that in Java using ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream classes. Now I want to do this with Dart. I have no idea about what I should use. I have also researched on google but I only found something for serialization of objects and saving them with json. But I am looking for something without json, like in Java.

I'm not english, sorry if I made some mistakes in writing. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: use json, nobody in clear mind will serialize objects in java  with `ObjectOutputStream`

Comment: Take a look into Hive... https://pub.dev/packages/hive

Comment: Thank you! It looks very useful!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to store and retrieve your objects to save some important information.
For fastest setup you can use HIVE pub.dev/packages/hive.

Other options are

- Serializing your object to son string and saving it to shared preference. https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
- Use an orm like moor to store and query large amounts of data. https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter